# The function doesn't return a list and Sage doesn't plot it

Tags: plot, point, sage

I've got the function `f(x,y)` and I want to iterate it a number of times and plot the resulting points. What I've done is:

```
def orbita(p,n):
    a = [p]
    for i in range(n-1):
        p = f(p[0],p[1])
        a.append(p)
    print a
```

When applied to the point `p = (1,2)` and asked for `n = 5` iterations, this function returns the following:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 5/2), (5/2, 29/20), (29/20, 1241/1450), (1241/1450, 7285162/5218405)]
```

Which is correct. However, when I try to plot this list of points by `point(orbita((1,2),5))`, I simply get an empty plot.

At first I thought that this was an issue with the fact that `point()` plots "either a single point (as a tuple), a list of points, a single complex number, or a list of complex numbers", quoted from [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/plotting/sage/plot/point.html#sage.plot.point.point), because I checked `type(orbita((1,2),5))` and got `NoneType`. However, when I tried to assign the list to a variable by `L = orbit((1,2),5)` my variable is empty, since typing `L` returns nothing, so I'm not sure anymore if that is the problem. If I copy the list and write:

```
point([(1, 2), (2, 5/2), (5/2, 29/20), (29/20, 1241/1450), (1241/1450, 7285162/5218405)])
```

The plot works perfectly, but I would like to use this function for plotting at least a couple of hundred points, so I wouldn't like to copy them every time. I'm new with both Sage and Python, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong at any level.

How can I print the outcome of the function `orbita(p,n)` or how can I modify it so that by typing `point(orbita(p,n))` I obtain a plot?

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem.

> this function returns the following:

No, it doesn't.  It *prints* the following.  As you correctly identify, it returns `None`.  So you have to have it *return* the list of tuples.  It looks like you are plenty experienced in Python to figure out how to do that, so I won't include the details, but please do follow up if you still have trouble.

Comment: (By the way, on this site it's typical to have a "minimal working example", though in this case it didn't really matter what `f` was.)

Comment: Working now, thanks! A long time ago I used C, and I recalled that `print` used to be more useful than `return`, I guess this is not always the case in other languages.

Comment: It often *is* more useful!  Just not the same.  Indeed, in Python the object returned looks quite different from the printed representation of that object - try making a very large matrix in Sage, for instance.

Comment: By the way, if this did correctly answer your question, you can accept it; if not, let me know how to help! :)